# invalid arithmetic operatior

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to multiply a integer value with a decimal `value = 2*1.5`. but how it gives me this **error**,`"invalid arithmetic operator"`.

I researched online and most of the solution provided is just to add that | bc behind the decimal value but however I tried it and it still doesn't work,

```
results=$((2*"1.5"|bc))
echo $results
```

Comment: Try backslashing the `*`. You may be getting unintended glob-expansion.

Comment: still have the error despite putting a backslash the *

Comment: `results=$(echo 2*"1.5" | bc )`

Comment: @devnull quotes around 1.5 are not necessary (at least in bash 4.3): `results=$(echo 2*1.5 | bc)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
results=`bc <<< "scale=2; 2*1.5"`
echo $results
```

here scale=2 means it will consider 2 decimal places

Please don't forget "`" tilde sign which is important above

Comment: I am glad it worked for you

If you found it correct please accpet answer (Click on right mark near to my answer)

Comment: if you are concerned of decimal values you can change scale values according to your accuracy

Comment: Please don't use backticks! backticks were in use in the middle-age. Since then, we discovered that it's much better to use `$(...)` as it's nestable and much prettier! So `results=$(bc <<< "scale=2; 2*1.5")` is much better.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf :  I agree on point ..

fact is even I use c style arithmetic but somewhere on Solaris and aix I faced issue so I was rescused with backticks & basics

Comment: C style arithmatics were included from bash version 3.2.
if you have machine running lower version then has to stick on basics

Comment: Dear, I'm not talking about shell arithmetics but about command substitution, that was already present in bash 3.2.

Comment: While you are discussing it, the backtick is incorrectly called a tilde in your explanation...

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the following:

```
echo "2*1.5" | bc
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$a =2;
$a =(float)$a;
$b=1.5;
echo $a*$b;
```

Comment: This is not [tag:bash].

Comment: This is in PHP while the question is asking about Bash. This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).